# Why does my footer have an empty box surrounding it?

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm trying to place a footer at the bottom of my page, but wind up with unwanted whitespace at the bottom. How can I correct that? The following is my HTML and CSS:

```css
body{
  min-height:100vh;
  position:relative;
}

.page-wrap{
  padding-bottom:50px;
}


footer{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:red;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="page-wrap">
        <nav>
          <h2>Header</h2>
        </nav>
        <main>
          <h2>Content</h2>
        </main>
      </div>
      <footer><h2>Footer</h2></footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I'm unsure what is creating it.

Comment: The codepen works fine for me. Please add a screenshot.

Comment: Please don't send people to the other site to see the other part of the code, *especially* when it's short enough to include your question! Makes it harder for people to understand the question AND the answers. I'll fix this time.

Comment: you have the margin of the body + the margin of the h2 + you are setting a fixed height so the margin of h2 is overflowing

Answer (score 0):

Just add below mentioned CSS code. Hope this help you.

```
footer h2 { margin: 0; }
```

Comment: Please explain why you think that solves it (such as suppresses all element margins, *including* the lower margin). Which leads to the question, shouldn't you fix that to make it specific to the lower margin only just as a matter of coding precision. Generally safer to avoid sloppy extra unneeded changes in coding. Bad habit that can create some really hard to find errors in code for you at some point. Better to keep each statement as focused, clear, responsible, documented and specific to the intended purpose as possible. Spares you nightmares later!

Comment: https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/cssmarginandpadding.png

Comment: footer{height:50px;} height only issue when we h2 tag height is increased so white space came

Comment: You could at least refine it by `footer h2 { margin-bottom: 0 };`

Comment: Or you can fix it for the whole body: `html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` or `html, body { margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0; }`, etc... whatever *really* solves the problem specifically or generically in a very conscious, clear and intended way considering future code evolution.